# Ubuntu Font Settings Description

Tags: 16.04, fonts, system-settings, gsettings

When you go font settings of system, you see Default Font, Document Font, Monospace Font, Window Title Font...

But what is `document-font` and where does it effect?

Comment: Are you accessing these font names using `Unity Tweak Tool`?

Comment: Sounds like it refers to *serif* font types, which are typically used in documents, e.g. LibreOffice Writer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_Ubuntu_Desktop_Fonts) a pretty good (if dated) description of display fonts in Ubuntu.

Quoting from that section:

> The Ubuntu GNOME desktop allows fonts to be specified for a number of different display categories:
>
> - Application font - The font used to display text in application windows. This also changes the font used to display items such as the menus in the desktop panel.
> - Document font - Specifies the font that is to be used when displaying document text in an application.
> - Desktop font - The font used to display text under the icons on the desktop (such as folder names).
> - Window title font - The font used on the text in window titles.
> - Fixed width font - Specifies the font to be used when the system needs to display fixed width font. A prime example of this is the text that is rendered in a Terminal window.
> - In terms of font selection options, fonts may be specified by type (Utopia, Serif, Monospace etc), style (Regular, Bold, Italic) and size (10pt, 11pt etc).

Comment: OK that's natural explanation also you can understand from the "document" name. But in today which application uses this setting to change its viewing font? All of the utilities have its own options for the font.